# Is it correct when ping.Result.Options.DontFragment gives false when sent true?

Tags: c#, ping

I use:

```
pingOptions.DontFragment = true;
```

but in result:

```
pingTask.Result.Options.DontFragment.ToString()
```

I get the value is false. I checked code several Times. Is it normal behaviour? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the PingReply class provides information from the resulting Send or SendAsync call. So it is the reply of the Endpoint. Because you set DontFragment it doesn't mean that the Endpoint should do that too:

> The DontFragment value specified in the ICMP echo request controls
>   packet fragmentation. If DontFragment is true and the packet size
>   exceeds the maximum transmission unit of the network path taken by the
>   packet, the packet is discarded and the PacketTooBig error is
>   returned.

Comment: But I don't get any errors on my side: Status: Success. RoundtripTime: 42ms.

Comment: Yes, the server just didn't set the flag to enable DontFragment. It doesn't mean that it didn't work. You ping the server, the server replies but it just doesn't set the DontFragment.